# How do setBounds in Google Maps API v2?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm upgrading some code written for Google Maps API v2, and I wish to set the bounds of the map (top, left, bottom, right), rather than the centre.

I notice that there's a [GMap2.getBounds](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/reference.html#GMap2.getBounds) but I can't seem to find a method which allows me to set the bounds.

How can I do this in Google Maps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found a way to do a setBounds here: http://www.mymapofjapan.com/blog/setting-size-and-zoom-level-of-maps/

```
var bounds = new GLatLngBounds; 
bounds.extend(new GLatLng( South, West )); 
bounds.extend(new GLatLng( North, East )); 
map.setCenter(bounds.getCenter(), map.getBoundsZoomLevel(bounds));
```

Because Google Maps has discrete zoom levels you probably won't be able to set it to exactly the bounds you wanted, so you might need to call map.getBounds(); afterwards to show the user the actual bounds they are looking at.